# Jquery Clone object with all nested elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, clone

I want to clone a JQM radio option and insert it at the end. The problem is `clone()` doesn't copy all the nested elements(dynamically generated). It just copies the first children not all the descendent. The generated content of radio option contains label element that has descendent elements too, but for some reason they don't clone.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aSKBW/7/

Comment: Instead of cloning it, create a new one and initialize it. I would post this as an answer, but i don't know the method to initialize it right off hand.

Comment: yeah that would be much better, but I am more concerned here what's exactly happening.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't clone the descendants? Your `.find('label')` seems to be working, and changing your `console.log`s to do `[0].outerHTML` shows the full content in the clone.

Comment: @am not i am  yeah I am getting the label element but not it's children which are present in real object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.clone()` is not truncating your selection, you are :). When you do this:

```
new_option.find('label').text('Red');
```

You are overwriting the HTML structure of the `label` element which looks like this:

```
<label for="sky-color-2" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Green</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-off ui-icon-shadow"></span>
    </span>
</label>
```

After you mess with the `.text()` function it looks like this:

```
<label for="sky-color-2" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last ui-btn-up-c">Red</label>
```

The fix is to target the `.ui-btn-text` element and change it's text:

```
new_option.find('.ui-btn-text').text('Red');
```

Here is an updated version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aSKBW/13/

Don't feel too bad, it's a very common mistake when getting used to jQuery Mobile and how it adds so much structure to the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a normal input and label like before:

```
$('<input type="radio" name="sky-color" value="red" id="sky-color-' + index + '" class="custom" />    <label for="sky-color-' + index + '">Red</label>');
```

then you trigger the `create` event on the top div

```
$('#slide21').trigger('create');
```

And because you append in the end you have to remove some classes from the previous label:

```
last.find('label').removeClass('ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last');
```

An Update of your Fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/aSKBW/16/

Comment: I know it was too late, but I was already working on it, so I don't want to hide what I achieved ;)

Comment: Nice touch with removing the rounded-corners. The fix to the actual problem was a bit simpler though.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just need to pass 'true' to deep copy?:

```
.clone(true)
```

> Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.
>
> **.clone ( withDataAndEvents )** Version Added : 1.0 withDataAndEvents : A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should
> be copied along with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will
> be copied as well.
>
> **.clone ( withDataAndEvents deepWithDataAndEvents )** Version Added : 1.5 withDataAndEvents : A Boolean indicating whether event handlers
> and data should be copied along with the elements. The default value
> is false. *For 1.5.0 the default value is incorrectly true. This will
> be changed back to false in 1.5.1 and up.
>
> **deepWithDataAndEvents** : A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be
> copied. By default its value matches the first argument's value (which
> defaults to false).

Comment: jQuery's `.clone()` always does a deep clone. The `deep` referred to in the docs indicates if jQuery data should also be cloned deep.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to clone it here, take a look.  You end up with the exact same values and IDs which can be a problem, but it does work.  http://jsfiddle.net/aSKBW/9/

Clone has 2 options .clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-option').click(function(e){
        $('.ui-radio:eq(0)').clone(true, true).appendTo('.ui-controlgroup-controls');
        $('.ui-radio:eq(1)').clone(true, true).appendTo('.ui-controlgroup-controls');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

A common solution for this kind of thing is to serialize your object then deserialize it into a new object.

Depending on what libraries or frameworks you are using you may have functions built in that allow you to do this.

I use knockoutjs which allows you to do this via ko.toJSON utility function which converts the object to a JSON string.

I have yet to see any generic solution that will properly handle serialization and deserialization of ANY object no matter how complex, if someone has one of these please post it here it would be useful to a lot of folks.